# Search Array for Keyword Return Key

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I've done some searching and have found similar questions but most of them have string keys and not numerical. Basically this is what I would like to achieve:

Sample Array

```
 Array (
      [0] => comments=DISABLED
      [1] => img_carousel=red.jpg,yellow.png,blue.jpg
      [2] => twitter=http://www.twitter.com
 )
```

Running something like this:

```
 $img_carousel = explode('=', $arr[array_search('img_carousel', $arr)]);
```

will return:

```
 Array (
      [0] => img_carousel
      [1] => red.jpg,yellow.png,blue.jpg
 )
```

However, it does not and only returns 0/FALSE. I'm guessing it is because array_search searches for an exact match and not for a keyword within a string?

I tried to use preg_grep, unfortunately, I just can't seem to understand regex and searching for a literal string has proven to be too difficult for me... :{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$img_carousel = explode('=', array_shift(preg_grep('/img_carousel=/', $arr)))
```

Comment: That will throw a warning under Strict standards, I think.  `array_shift()` takes an array reference as its argument, and you're passing the output of a function.

Comment: well, it did what i was looking for, however, if @Michael is correct, how would you comply with Strict standards? And will this work in PHP 5.3?

Comment: @lemonpole Store the output of `preg_grep()` to a variable, then use that variable as the argument to `array_shift()` instead of the `preg_grep()` call directly.

Comment: @lemonpole: just split split it into two lines instead of a single line of code. Yes it'll work in 5.3

Answer (score 2):

As of php 5.3 you could follow this sample:

```
$result = array_filter($arr, function($e) {
    return strpos($e, 'img_carousel') !== false;
});
```

or if you use old versions:

```
function ifElementContainsImgCarousel($e)
{
    return strpos($e, 'img_carousel') !== false;
}
$result = array_filter($arr, 'ifElementContainsImgCarousel');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to get the elements which contains your keyword.

```
array_filter($sample_array, function($var) use ($keyword) {return strpos($var, $keyword) !== false;})
```

Comment: What is `$keyword` in your sample?

Comment: @zerkms The Keyword in the question title, just something like 'img_carousel'.

Comment: how is it supposed to be passed to the anonymous function variable scope?